# How to update mysql db on session destroy

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have question about updating mysql db field with enum 1 and 0 and when the user log in it change it to 1 but when user log out i tried doing this but it won't work...
Also  I tried make it as button and if btn is pressed do something and then go to logout.php but it didnt work ...

So my code is this ...

```
<?php include_once('connect.php');
$logger = $_SESSION["login"];
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();


    $mysqli = "UPDATE table SET field='0' WHERE email='$logger'";
    if(mysqli_query($con, $mysqli)){

header("Location: index.php");}else echo "Something went wrong!";
?>
```

Comment: Is `table` your actual table name :P?

Comment: no i don't want to write my table name :D

Comment: when you logout, you're setting a $logout variable from session. Check if that variable is holding proper value.

Comment: ^^ *`$logger` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't to do with the other two answers, @Gopal states that you should destroy after unsetting the session, however you are setting the variable before unsetting the session. @Marmik also doesn't solve the issue.

Your problem lies here:

```
$logger = $_SESSION["login"];
session_start();
```

You're trying to access the session variable before you actually start the session. This is going to give you a blank `$logger` which you may find if you use `echo $logger`.

So, how do we solve this. Essentially, we just swap two lines around, so that `session_start()` is before we try accessing the session variables.

```
session_start();
$logger = $_SESSION["login"];
```

If this fails, you may want to check that `$_SESSION["login"]` has actually been set in the first place with a quick `echo $_SESSION['login'];` after `session_start();`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it works mine stupid move to put session after... :D

Answer (score 0):

Give session_unset(); session_destroy(); After update query of the table.

Comment: He's setting the value of `$logger` before he unsets the session.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is you can check the session that he is really logedin or not

***On Logout.php***

```
<?php 

 @session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])){

include_once('connect.php');

$logger = $_SESSION["login"];



$mysqli = "UPDATE table SET field='0' WHERE email='$logger'";

if(mysqli_query($con, $mysqli)){

    session_unset();
    session_destroy();


    header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else {
         echo "Something went wrong!"
    };

 }
?>
```

Comment: You have to start a session before accessing the `$_SESSION` variables.